# Android Architecture Navigation - How to navigate to specific place in Nav Graph building back stack

Tags: back-stack, android-architecture-navigation

I have a linear wizard created with Android Arch Navigation and I would like to start it at specific location building back stack as with natural user navigation. 
So I have tried this deep link building:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("myarg", "From Widget");
 new NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
    .setGraph(R.navigation.mobile_navigation)
    .setDestination(R.id.step_fragment)
    .setArguments(args)
    .createPendingIntent().send();
```

The problem with this approach is that it doesn't build back stack correctly as user will be build navigating  Step 1 -> Step 2 -> ... -> Step N 
It only holds Step 1 -> Step N, i.e. start destination and target destination of navigation graph. This is not what I want.

Second simple approach is to just call multiple times `navigate()` on `navController`. But as it seems simple it doesn't work

```
 protected fun navigateTo(step: Int) {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        if(step >= 0 && step < stepFragments.count()) {
            // go to step-th fragment
            if(navController.currentDestination.id != stepFragments.first()) return

            for(i in 0 until step) {
                navController.navigate(stepFragments[i])
            }
            navController.navigate(stepFragments[step])
        } else if(step == stepFragments.count()) {
            // go to confirm fragment
            navController.navigate(confirmFragment)
        } else {
            throw IndexOutOfBoundsException("Step index is out of wizard bounds!")
        }
    }
```

It navigates correctly but then the created back stack is odd, i.e.  Back button seems to work, but **onNavigatedListener** listener from

```
navController.addOnNavigatedListener(this::onNavigatedListener)
```

is not called correctly. So I cannot listen for fragment changes in wizard. Moreover NavController seems to be break, as consecutive button listener's navController.navigate(actionId) throws error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination 
>   is unknown to this NavController

**UPDATE!**

Intercepting onBackPressed() with debugger seems to show that Back Button Press doesn't call navController.popBackStack() and the navController.currentDestination property doesn't change. But inside NavHostFragment the fragment is changing.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this multi-step **navController.navigate()** works Ok. 
And fixing of back-stack while pressing Back button to expected behaviour can be achieved by overriding default onBackPressed() behaviour to something like this:

```
 //region BACK PRESSED - CUSTOM BACK STACK HANDLING
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if(!findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).popBackStack()) {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
    //endregion
```

And for the record

```
protected fun navigateTo(step: Int) {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        if(step >= 0 && step < stepFragments.count()) {
            // go to step-th fragment
            if(navController.currentDestination.id != stepFragments.first()) return

            for(i in 0 until step) {
                navController.navigate(stepFragments[i])
            }
            navController.navigate(stepFragments[step])
        } else if(step == stepFragments.count()) {
            // go to confirm fragment
            navController.navigate(confirmFragment)
        } else {
            throw IndexOutOfBoundsException("Step index is out of wizard bounds!")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think it is a workaround and there are cases with screen rotation. I think it is some issue and I will also send to issue tracker limited wizard with this bug example. Maybe they will solve this issue